# How to generate a random number every 5 seconds in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, setinterval

I know this question has already been asked and answered, but I can't seem to get the expected output.

```
let ranNum = 0;

setTimeout(function(){   
  ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1); 
}, 5000);
```

When I run this my chrome browser keeps generating random numbers over and over until I stop the program. I tried this with setInterval too. What I want to happen is to generate a random number every 5 seconds and add that to another variable in my code.(so this variable should display a different number every five seconds). I'm doing this in my client side - React.js and was wondering if there's another way to do this with react. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear-what do you mean by "display" or "add that to another variable"? Your code right now (it's a timeout not interval) should assign a random integer between 1 and 100 in 5 seconds to `ranNum`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `useEffect` hook to set the interval and update a state, then display the state

```js
const RandomNumber = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0);
  
  // add side effect to component
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // create interval
    const interval = setInterval(
      // set number every 5s
      () => setNumber(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1)),
      5000
    );

    // clean up interval on unmount
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return <p>{number}</p>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<RandomNumber />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This. you'll either need to use the hooks or old class lifecycle methods to make sure that components render and update properly. And clear the interval after component is unmounted to prevent starting multiple counters without ever clearing them up.